# Concat a constant value to sql SELECT result

Tags: mysql, sql

I am writing a sql code for a project which contains a nested select query.
This is the part of the query I actually want to get.

`"AND s.thirdparty in (2,3,5)";`

I can get values 3 and 5 easily with following code.

`"AND s.thirdparty in (select hid from tblname where col1='xx')"`

which returns,

`"AND s.thirdparty in (3,5)"`

but I cannot get value 2 that way. So can I just add it to the result of the nested query so I have the full query I need?

Comment: Check you select statement what its give. It’s really hard to understand what you actually want share you actually condition and data you have. To understand what is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `2` is a known constant use UNION ALL in the subquery:

```
AND s.thirdparty in (select hid from tblname where col1='xx' union all select 2)
```

or:

```
AND (s.thirdparty in (select hid from tblname where col1='xx') or s.thirdparty = 2)
```

Comment: yes you are correct. union or union all both can be used. thank you